# Representing triangular matrix in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, matrix

I have an assignment which says I have to read from file the distances between 20 citys each. I wonder how to handle that data in the application. I thought of multidimensional array, something like `Distances(0, 1, 0)=500` which means that the distance between city0 and city1 is 500 miles. Also I think this is a waste of memory because `Distances(0, 1, 0)` and `Distances(1, 0, 0)` is the same thing. My mentor told me to use triangular matrix to save the  data into the app. Can you show me an example of a similar data handling or some other idea of how to handle the data? I just can't imagine it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think he means is something like this:
http://www.arenalogisticsinc.com/images/chart4.jpg

Basically a 2-D array - And if you want to save space, just remove the top half of the array since it will have repetitions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of arrays. A multidimensional array is useful if you have a consistent array size for each of the inner arrays, but you want your first array to have length=0, the second to have length=1, etc... So, actually, you don't even need the first array - as it is just empty.

```
Dim triangle As Array(19)

For i = 0 To 18

    Dim innerArray(i+1) As Integer

    triangle(i) = innerArray

Next
```